# How to make redirecte to link, which return response from API php?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

Situation - i got form on site, which action on api.php of partner system, data send success, partner system receive it, than it response on request with success and data - url, which user should be redirected.

{"status":true,"data":"https://client.domain.com/en-US/Account/autologin?Email=mail@yahoo.com&Password=password", etc.}

Code of API.php

```
    <?php

$apidata = array(
"firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],
"lastname" => $_POST['lastname'],
"email" => $_POST['email'],
"password" => $_POST['password'],
"phone" => $_POST['phone'],
"userip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
"sub" => "sub1",
"so" => "sub2",
"ai" => "ID",
"ci" => "ID",
"gi" => "ID"
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://partner.media/api/signup/procform',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($apidata),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'x-trackbox-username: username',
    'x-trackbox-password: password',
    'x-api-key: apikey',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),

));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```

This code works well - it send data once, but i don't understand, how to get "data":"https://client.domain.com/en-US/Account/autologin?Email=mail@yahoo.com&Password=password" from response, send apidata there too and So user can be redirected there automatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: The response is JSON, so you decode that, and then access the `data` property (or key) of the resulting object (or array.)

Comment: Unclear though, what you mean by _“send apidata there too”_ - what exactly do you want to send there, and why? If you need to output parts of the API response on the target page you want to redirect the user to - then you should store it into the session in the part that makes the API call, so that you can access it again from there on that target page.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly. I think the only part your missing is, that the client side must call your api with the needed parameters. The echo $response sends the client (which is waiting for a response) the data back and you have to do the redirect on the client side.